# Haskell Assignment - direction needed to split a String into words

Tags: haskell

we started a paper on Haskell a few weeks ago and just received our first assignment. I'm aware that SO doesn't like homework questions, so I'm not going to ask how to do it. Instead, it would be very much appreciated if anyone could push me in the right direction with this. Seeing as it might not be a specific question, would it be more appropriate in a discussion / community wiki?

**Question:** Tokenize a String, that is: "Hello, World!" -> ["Hello", "World"]
Coming from a Java background, I have to forget everything about the usual way to go about this. The problem is that I am still very clueless with Haskell. This is what I've come up with:

```
module Main where

main :: IO()
main = do putStrLn "Type in a string:\n"
          x <- getLine
          putStrLn "The string entered was:"
          putStrLn x
          putStrLn "\n"
          print (tokenize x)

tokenize :: String -> [String]
tokenize [] = []
tokenize l = token l ++ tokenize l

token :: String -> String
token [] = []
token l = takeWhile (isAlphaNum) l
```

What would be the first glaring mistake?
Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow does like homework questions, as long as you tag them appropriately and show what you have tried (and that is an effort, even if misguided). This one is okay.

Comment: One thing you haven't quite forgotten from your Java background is that variables are immutable in Haskell. It seems like you're expecting that expression `token l` will modify `l`. It will not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first glaring mistake is

```
tokenize l = token l ++ tokenize l
```

`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` appends two lists of the same type. Since `token :: String -> String` (and `type String = [Char]`), the type of `tokenize` that is inferred from that line is `tokenize :: String -> String`.
You should use `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` here.

The next mistake in that line is that in the recursive call, you pass the same input `l` once again, so you have an infinite recursion, always doing the same without change. You have to remove the first token (and a bit more) from the input for the argument to the recursive call.

Another problem is that your `token` supposes that the input begins with alphanumeric characters.

You also need a function that ensures that condition for what you pass to `token`.

Comment: I'll come back to this in the morning. 2am is no good. +1 though.

Answer (score 4):

This line results in an infinite list (which is OK, since Haskell is lazy, so the list only gets constructed "on demand"), because it is recurring with no change in the arguments:

```
tokenize l = token l ++ tokenize l
```

We can visualise what is happening when tokenize is called as:

```
tokenize l = token l ++ tokenize l
           = token l ++ (token l ++ tokenize l)
           = token l ++ (token l ++ (token l ++ tokenize l))
           = ...
```

To stop this happening, you need to change what the argument to `tokenize` so that it recurs sensibly:

```
tokenize l = token l ++ tokenize <something goes here>
```

Comment: Would it work if I `drop` `the length of the token from l + 1` before the recursive call?

Answer (score 2):

As others already pointed out your mistake, just a little hint: While you found already the very useful `takeWhile` function, you should have a look at [`span`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aspan), as this could be even more helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

This has something in it that feels similar to a parser monad.  However, as you're a newcomer to Haskell, it's unlikely that you're in a position to understand how parsing monads work (or use them in your code) quite yet.  To give you the basics, consider what you want:

```
tokenize :: String -> [String]
```

This takes a String, chomps it up into more pieces, and generates a list of strings corresponding to the words in the input string.  How might we represent this?  What we want to do is find a function that processes a single string, and at the first sign of whitespace, adds that string on to the sequence of words.  But *then* you have to process what's left over. (I.e., the rest of the string.)  For example, let's say you want to tokenize:

> The brown fox jumped

You first pull out "The" and then continue processing " brown fox jumped" (note the space at the beginning of the second string).  You will do this recursively, so naturally you will need a recursive function.

The natural solution that sticks out is to take something where you *accumulate* a set of strings you've tokenized so far, keep munching on the current input until you hit whitespace, then also accumulate what you've seen in the current string (this leads to an implementation where you're mostly consing stuff, and then occasionally reversing stuff).

Answer (score -1):

Your exercise seemed a bit challenging to me so I decided to solve it just for self-training. Here's what I came up with:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

splitByAnyOf yss xs = 
  foldr (\ys acc -> concat $ map (splitBy ys) acc) [xs] yss

splitBy ys xs = 
  case (precedingElements ys xs, succeedingElements ys xs) of
    (Just "", Just s) -> splitBy ys s
    (Just p, Just "") -> [p]
    (Just p, Just s) -> p : splitBy ys s
    otherwise -> [xs]

succeedingElements ys xs = 
  fromMaybe Nothing . find isJust $ map (stripPrefix ys) $ tails xs

precedingElements ys xs = 
  fromMaybe Nothing . find isJust $ map (stripSuffix ys) $ inits xs
  where
    stripSuffix ys xs = 
      if ys `isSuffixOf` xs then Just $ take (length xs - length ys) xs
      else Nothing

main = do
  print $ splitBy "!" "Hello, World!"
  print $ splitBy ", " "Hello, World!"
  print $ splitByAnyOf [", ", "!"] "Hello, World!"
```

outputs:

```
["Hello, World"]
["Hello","World!"]
["Hello","World"]
```